# Highstock graph is not showing when only single data is present

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I am using [Highstock](http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/) to draw graph on my website. It is working fine. But when only single data is present I have to hover over to see the graph data. Please help me to find a solution for this.

Comment: for quick replay, please create a jsfidle example.

Comment: With single data how can graph drawn only single point will plot.

Comment: here is a jsfidle example http://jsfiddle.net/9LLXs/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use markers:

```
plotOptions: {
    series: {
        marker: {
            enabled: true
        }
    }
},
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/9LLXs/3/)**